# Hiding Apple ID from Whatsapp

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id, whatsapp.app

For privacy purposes I use different email accounts for different tiers of services and correspondence, including social media. My Apple ID address is NEVER used or given out and I use alias’es for my iCloud email correspondence.

I know that Facebook links profiles among their different services, in many cases through the phone number, so they basically know that it is the same person in Facebook/Instagram than the one on Whatsapp.

My question is:

**Does Whatsapp have access to my Apple ID address? Or is the address not shared on iOS, although Whatsapp may use the account to do the iCloud Backups? I’m askimg because by no means I want to be a linkage between my social media email accounts (or any other address) to my Apple ID address.**

Also, when an app tries to use Apple ID to create an account on iOS, you always have the option to “Hide email address” from the app. Hopefully thats the case for Whatsapp (but what about the iCloud backups?)

Thank you

Comment: On the topic of that last bit - Sign in with Apple is completely different from iCloud/iCloud Backups and won't come into play unless you specifically see that type of button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer; no. If you want to know what the app does share its linked under the privacy portion of the app's page:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997

From what I can see there, your Apple ID isn't even shared with the app's devs.

Comment: How does Whastapp then connect my iCloud (for backups) without knowing the Apple ID? Also in the Developer Notes in the App Store, it says that Apple uses User ID / Device ID, are any of those the Apple ID?

Thank you